# MSP430 DSP HELP :Can anyone give me a sample DSP script in C/C++

Tags: c++, audio, signal-processing

Is there any pre written dsp codes for the msp430 series mircrocontroller?

Im working on a (Audio) DSP project and just wondering if there are any sample (Open source) DSP example that are written in c or c++, for my MSP430 Chip. I just want something as a guideline so i can program my own script using the ACD and DCA on my board for sampling.

http://focus.ti.com/docs/toolsw/folders/print/msp-exp430f5438.html

Thats my board, MSP430F5438 Experimenter Board, from what i herd it can run dsp script via the USB connection with the computer.

Im using CCS ( From TI, code composer studio) and Octave/Matlab.

Just any DSP example scripts or sites that will help me create my own would be appreciated.

What im tying to do,

Partial audio (sampled) track --> Nyquist rate sampling --> over- and undersampling --> reconstruction of the audio track.